# Issue With Parsing Text File and Trimming Spaces - Batch File

Tags: parsing, batch-file, command-line

Here is a sample of the input file:

```
Changed the current scope context to 192.168.1.0 scope.

Type : N - NONE, D - DHCP B - BOOTP, U - UNSPECIFIED, R - RESERVATION IP
============================================================================================
IP Address      - Subnet Mask    - Unique ID           - Lease Expires        -Type -Name   
============================================================================================

192.168.1.1     - 255.255.255.0  - 00-50-60-02-d5-cf   -1/17/2014 2:20:58 PM   -D-  TBH-CBHS-Provider
192.168.1.7     - 255.255.255.0  - 00-50-60-82-09-e7   -1/14/2014 1:39:04 PM   -D-  Director-of-ASAP
192.168.1.8     - 255.255.255.0  - 00-50-60-82-0b-6d   -1/17/2014 2:20:44 PM   -D-  Soc-Work-Ser-FAP
```

Here is the file that is supposed to parse it (EDIT: Parsing code included (which also explains some of the seemingly redundant variables):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET scope=%1
FOR /F "skip=6 tokens=1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 delims=-" %%B IN (%1.txt) DO (
set ipaddress=%%B
set ipaddress=%ipaddress: =%
set mac=%%C-%%D-%%E-%%F-%%G-%%H
set mac=%mac: =%
set lease=%%I
set lease=%lease: =%
echo %scope%,%ipaddress%,%mac%,%%I >> printer_scopes.txt)
```

And finally, here is what is output to printer_scopes.txt:

```
192.168.1.0,Command completed successfully.,-----,1/17/2014 2:20:58 PM    
192.168.1.0,Command completed successfully.,-----,1/14/2014 1:39:04 PM    
192.168.1.0,Command completed successfully.,-----,1/17/2014 2:20:44 PM
```

Now, I know I don't have the code in presently to trim spaces, but that's because all it does is trim spaces from the string "Command completed successfully.".  Where is that string coming from?  Why isn't mac being set properly?  Help!

Comment: Can you post your trimming code and your expected output? The code you've posted, when run in Windows 7 Pro x64, outputs: `test,192.168.1.8     , 00-50-60-82-0b-6d   ,1/14/2014 1:39:04 PM
test,192.168.1.8     , 00-50-60-82-0b-6d   ,1/17/2014 2:20:44 PM` (which is `%scope%,%ipaddress%,%mac%,%%I` exactly).

Comment: works (nearly) fine for me (WIN7). You don't need the `ipaddress`-variable. Just `echo %scope%,%%B,%mac%...` (if you have to use the variable, use delayed expansion and `!ipaddress!`

Comment: ... same with `mac`-variable. You don't really need it. If you use it, use delayed expansion and `!mac!`

Comment: If you show what you expect in the output then it would help to fix any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like This :

```
@echo off&cls
SET scope=%1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=7 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 delims=- " %%a in (%1.txt) do (
                   set $IP=%%a
                   set $SUBNET_MASK=%%b 
                   set $MAC=%%c-%%d-%%e-%%f-%%g-%%h
                   echo %scope%,!$IP!,!$MAC!,%%i>> printer_scopes.t)
```

Comment: The combination of EnableDelayedExpansion - which I had seen elsewhere - and the !var! syntax - which I had not - did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
DEL  printer_scopes.txt
SET scope=q21031672
FOR /F "skip=6 tokens=1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9delims=- " %%B IN (q21031672.txt) DO (
set ipaddress=%%B
set mac=%%C-%%D-%%E-%%F-%%G-%%H
echo %scope%,%%B,%%C-%%D-%%E-%%F-%%G-%%H,%%I >> printer_scopes.txt
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Your fundamental problem is `delayed expansion`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the ENTIRE block is parsed and **THEN** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **AT THE TIME THE BLOCK IS PARSED** - before the block is executed.

The bogus values that you are seeing are those that were already established when the batch or section was started, possibly from previous activity. For this reason, it is common practice to invoke `setlocal` after the `@echo`, which backs out any changes made to the environment by the batch when the batch ends.

Next problem is your positioning of the `delims` phrase - if you want <kbd>Space</kbd> included, it needs to be last, otherwise batch doesn't know whether it's included or excluded in the `delims` list. Best to always place last.

`FOR/F` ignores empty lines, so your `skip` may need adjusting. I simply set the value of %1 to a constant `q2103262` since that suits my testing.

Not clear whether you need the variables; in this case the output can be generated directly from the meatvariables used so there appears to be no point, but I left them there anyway.

Comment: I wish I could give you partial credit - your explanation is clear, and explains some concepts I was fuzzy on.  Unfortunately, the EnableDelayedExpansion and !var! is what actually did the trick for me.  Nevertheless, I greatly appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

your mac-address is not shown, because the whole block between `(` and `)`is parsed at once, and `%mac%` is empty when parsing. But you don't really need `%mac%` (same problem with `%ipaddress%` - same solution):

```
@echo off
SET scope=%1
FOR /F "delims=- skip=8 tokens=1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" %%B IN (%1.txt) DO (
echo %scope%,%%B,%%C-%%D-%%E-%%F-%%G-%%H,%%I >> printer_scopes.txt
)
```

(also you are not using `%scope%` in this code)

The string "command completed successfully" does not occur with my windows (Win7)